# Cannot add actions to OS X Preferences menu

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

In trying to add action items to the default OS X menu, I'm following [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html#details). Below is a short script that, when run, produces:

> QMenu: No OSMenuRef created for popup menu

My (apparently inadequate) searches have not revealed any real clues as to what next, or if this is even possible to do.

Script:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
from PyQt4 import QtGui
menu = QtGui.QMenuBar()
action = QtGui.QAction('Apref', app)
action.setMenuRole(QtGui.QAction.PreferencesRole)
menu.addAction(action)
```

Details:

- OS X 10.10
- Python 2.7
- Qt version: '4.8.7'
- SIP version:'4.16.9'
- PyQt version: '4.11.4'

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: The misconception that I had is that when things are sucked into the standard OS X "Preferences", they would all be attached to a menu under "Preferences". The reality is that only ONE action gets associated with Preferences and it is up to the developer to build the system desired. I figured this out by looking at what "Preferences" does with other applications: They always create some app-specific window.

So, without ado, here is a minimum script that implements Preferences. I have no doubt there is a more standard way of handling, but wanted to get this out there.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

def pmake(*args, **kwargs):
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    menu.addAction('This is an action')
    result = menu.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(10,10))
    print 'result="{}"'.format(result)

pact = QtGui.QAction('Preferences', app)
pact.triggered.connect(pmake)
pact.setMenuRole(QtGui.QAction.PreferencesRole)
pmenu = QtGui.QMenu('Preferences')
pmenu.addAction(pact)
menu = QtGui.QMenuBar()
menu.addMenu(pmenu)
```